# Vim: Change start up directory?

Tags: windows, vim, working-directory

When I start GVim and start writing my little program I'd like to save the file to the Desktop but it seems that Vim is starting the command line in:

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

How would I go about changing that to:

```
C:\Users\Casey
```

so then I could just:

```
:w Desktop\my_program.py
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Assuming you're starting gvim from an icon/shortcut in Windows (from the kind of paths you supply), you can change the starting directory (completely independent from the fact that it IS gvim: it would be the same from any other app!) by editing the "starting directory" property of that Windows icon/shortcut.

Comment: +1, this was exactly what I needed.  Incidentally, on Windows 7, if you set the Start In directory to `%USERPROFILE%`, you'll get the user's home directory like the OP wanted.

Answer (score 13):

Within vim, you can change the current directory with the `:cd` command:

```
:cd c:\users\casey
```

Comment: Or it can be `:cd $USERPROFILE` under VIM 7.3.

Answer (score 11):

I found this way to be better:

1. Open gVim
2. `:cd $vim`
3. `:e _gvimrc`
4. Add the following line:

   ```
   :cd c:\users\user\desktop\
   ```

I found that `:Ex` is slow on large directories like **c:\windows\system32\** (where gVim usually starts).

---

Also, here is my full **_gvimrc** in case anyone is interested. I prefer Consolas for coding. The tabstop setting helps when coding especially in Python, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is great for switching between buffers:

```
set guifont=Consolas:h12:cANSI
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
map <C-Tab> :bnext<cr>
map <C-S-Tab> :bprevious<cr>
:cd c:\users\user\desktop\
```

Answer (score 4):

How about changing your starting position?

`vim icon -> right click -> property -> shortcut -> Start in -> your path you want to change.`

but it works perfectly.

I think :cd yourpath also works. but it will change when you don't want to change.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:cd c:\users\casey`, 
after that save into session (in gVim there is button up and down in red, click on it and save as **mySessionProject.vim**). Next time you need to go to that directory, open that session (you can also use `:source mySessionProject.vim`)

for command line:

```
:mksession! yourdir/yourVimConfName.vim
```

to load

```
:source yourDir/yourVimConfName.vim
```

Comment: If you always want to start in this directory it's probably easier to put the cd command into your .gvimrc. Using sessions is nice for having multiple different "configurations" - this could also be used with desktop shortcuts where each shortcut would call something like "gvim -S sessionX.vim"

Comment: yep .. you are right blixtor. .. 
but with session, you can have different directory for each project.

like i store my project-1 in c:\project-1 
and project-2 in c:\project-2 
so when I need to edit files in first project i just need to open the session and I will be located to project-1 directory.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following to be very useful. I am on Windows 7 and vim 7.3.46, and am using gVim.

I edited startup settings, which wound up altering the _vimrc in `c:\Users\me\`.

I also tried using `:version` and editing the _vimrc files I found at `$VIM`, as well as the `_vimrc` I found at `c:\windows\system32`.

Editing those files to include `:cd c:\Users\me` did not result in my default startup directory changing after starting vim. I wanted my default directory to be `c:\Users\me\`, and editing `c:\Users\me\_vimrc` achieved that. That is I entered

`:e $MYVIMRC`

and added

`cd c:\Users\cnorton.Arlington1\`

to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Just to to put this up incase anyone needs it:
vimrc accepts enironmental parameters. you can put `cd $USERPROFILE` in your vimrc

Answer (score 0):

Use this mapping in your .vimrc file
`:cd $USERPROFILE\Desktop<cr>`

or the same shorter
`cd ~\Desktop<cr>`

A mapping that also displays afterwards the path instead of the command
`nmap <leader>d :cd ~\Desktop<cr>:pwd<cr>`

Answer (score 0):

Inside `init.vim`, I use:

```
lcd $HOME/Projects
```